# rightbarbuttomitem is out of bounds when I change orientation in splitviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, rightbarbuttonitem

I have a SplitViewController, with a rightbarbuttonitem on navigation that its'n resizing when I change the orientation from portrait to Landscape, my rightbarbuttonitem is out of bounds

The rightbarbuttomitem is a customview (blue color background).

I attach some pics of the problem:

[image: NavigationcController in portrait]

[image: NavigationController in landscape]

And my code:

in appdelegate:

```
masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithFeed:feedData];
    UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];

    detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithFeed:[feedData.secciones objectAtIndex:0]];
    [detailViewController setSeccionData:[feedData.secciones objectAtIndex:0]];
    UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];
    detailNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor getHexColorWithRGB:@"e2de09" alpha:1.0f];

    self.splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;

    masterViewController.delegate=detailViewController;
    self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNavigationController, detailNavigationController, nil];

    self.window.rootViewController=self.splitViewController;
```

and in my DetailViewController init the rightbarbuttonitem with a custom view:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=nil;
NSArray *buttons;

    buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"send",@"reload",nil];
    tools=[[Toolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 30) parentController:detalleDG buttons:buttons];

tools.delegate=self;    

UIBarButtonItem *btnRight=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools.view];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=btnRight;
```

I tried with 
detailNavigationController.navigationBar.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth; or 
 tools.view.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
but nothing

Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
tools=[[Toolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 30) parentController:detalleDG buttons:buttons];
```

Try change to this

```
tools=[[Toolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, xxxxx.frame.size.width, xxxx.frame.size.height) parentController:detalleDG buttons:buttons];
```

You may change the "xxxxx" to get width and height automatically, according to your screen size of bartool or screen of your view

Did it help?

Comment: My Toolbar was an UIView, so I tried to change it by a UIToolbar and it works now